# python: I can't give different colors to rectangles (in a list)

Tags: python-3.x, colors

```
color = pygame.Color(0,0,0) # color object to make color.hsva work

# ......... problem loop:

for i in range(number_lines):
    xco = random.randint(0, W)
    yco = random.randint(0, (H-100) // 6)*6
    breadth = random.randint(5, 111)
    COLOR = SINUS[yco]
    color.hsva = COLOR_list[COLOR]
    rectangles[i] = rectangle(xco, yco, breadth, 1, i, GREEN)
    print(color) # all colors different
    rectangles[i].fillColor = color # doesn't work - all same color

    COLOR_333list[i] = color # all the same, all equal last of the list - how????????
```

In fact, where there is GREEN, I had "color", but that didn't work.
Tried with fillColor, didn't work either.
I just put COLOR_333list[i] to test, and all colors in the list are the same.
What's the matter?

(I first did everything with list comprehension, but got the same problem)

Comment: Think about how many `pygame.Color` objects you're creating in total in this code.

Answer (score 0):

added:
c = copy.copy(color)
and could color the rectangle with c